# My code keeps skipping a part every iteration of a while() loop in C

Tags: c, while-loop

After the first iteration of my loop, it becomes a disgusting mess.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    double a, b; char op = 'a';

    while(op != 'E')
    {
        printf("Insert operator: \n");
        scanf("%c", &op);

        printf("Insert first number: \n");
        scanf("%lf", &a);

        printf("Insert second number: \n");
        scanf("%lf", &b);

        switch(op)
        {
            case '+': printf("%lf \n", (a + b)); break;

            case '-': printf("%lf \n", (a - b)); break;

            case '*': printf("%lf \n", (a * b)); break;

            case '/': printf("%lf \n", (a / b)); break;
        }

        op = 'a';


    }

    return 0;
}
```

The console looks like in the picture. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZnkq.png)

Transcript:

```
Insert operator:
+
Insert first number:
1
Insert second number:
2
3.000000
Insert operator:
Insert first number:
8
Insert second number:
-
Insert operator:
Insert first number:
2
Insert second number:
5
```

I'm new to coding and this is my first time on Stack Overflow, I'm sorry if I did something wrong like formatting my question. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Always check that read operations are successful. In your case you should check the result of `scanf`. And you will get a hint of what's wrong

Comment: `scanf("%c", &op);` -> `scanf(" %c", &op);` (**note:** the additional space) And... you cannot use any input function correctly without ***checking the return***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two (actually 3) primary problems:

1. You fail to remove the `'\n'` left in `stdin` after the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering `b` before attempting to read `op` again. The `"%c"` *format specifier* (along with `"%[...]"`) does not ignore *whitespace*, so you must manually add a `space` before the `" %c"` in your `scanf()` format string so that the *whitespace* is ignored;
2. Your handling of `op = 'a';` after the `switch()` statement ensures `op` never equals `'E'` which you use to exit the `while(op != 'E')` loop. You should test whether `op == 'E'` after `op` is read and break the loop there if the user enteres `'E'`. (which also means your loop can simply be `while(1)`
3. The biggest of all. You fail to check the return of any of your user-input functions `scanf()`. You cannot use any input function correctly (and especially `scanf()`) if you do not ***check the return***. You must handle at minimum 3-cases, 1 - good input, 2 - a *matching* or *input* failure, and 3 - `EOF`. If you fail to check the return, you invite all types of nasty results like *Undefined Behavior* when you attempt to access the value of a variable after input failed or an *infinite loop* where a *matching failure* occurs, character extraction from the input stream ceases, and the offending character remains in your input stream *unread*.

To handle reading and ***validating*** `op`, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    double a, b; char op = 'a';

    while (1) {
        /* read and VALIDATE operator */
        fputs ("\nInsert operator (+,-,*,/) : ", stdout);
        if (scanf (" %c", &op) != 1 || op == 'E')
            return 1;
        /* validate op is one of + - * / */
        if (op != '+' && op != '-' && op != '*' && op != '/') {
            fputs ("error: invalid operator.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
```

Then for each `a` and `b`, you can do:

```
        /* read and VALIDATE first number */
        fputs ("Insert first number       : ", stdout);
        if (scanf ("%lf", &a) != 1)
            return 1;
        /* read and VALIDATE second number */
        fputs ("Insert second number      : ", stdout);
        if (scanf ("%lf", &b) != 1)
            return 1;
```

(**note:** those are the bare minimum validations required and they don't accommodate any failure and recover, they simply check if input is valid or exits)

Putting it altogether, you can do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    double a, b; char op = 'a';

    while (1) {
        /* read and VALIDATE operator */
        fputs ("\nInsert operator (+,-,*,/) : ", stdout);
        if (scanf (" %c", &op) != 1 || op == 'E')
            return 1;
        /* validate op is one of + - * / */
        if (op != '+' && op != '-' && op != '*' && op != '/') {
            fputs ("error: invalid operator.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }

        /* read and VALIDATE first number */
        fputs ("Insert first number       : ", stdout);
        if (scanf ("%lf", &a) != 1)
            return 1;
        /* read and VALIDATE second number */
        fputs ("Insert second number      : ", stdout);
        if (scanf ("%lf", &b) != 1)
            return 1;

        switch(op) {
            case '+': printf ("\n  %g + %g = %g\n", a, b, (a + b)); break;
            case '-': printf ("\n  %g - %g = %g\n", a, b, (a - b)); break;
            case '*': printf ("\n  %g * %g = %g\n", a, b, (a * b)); break;
            case '/': printf ("\n  %g / %g = %g\n", a, b, (a / b)); break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/scanf_char

Insert operator (+,-,*,/) : +
Insert first number       : 4
Insert second number      : 5

  4 + 5 = 9

Insert operator (+,-,*,/) : -
Insert first number       : 4
Insert second number      : 5

  4 - 5 = -1

Insert operator (+,-,*,/) : *
Insert first number       : 4
Insert second number      : 5

  4 * 5 = 20

Insert operator (+,-,*,/) : /
Insert first number       : 4
Insert second number      : 5

  4 / 5 = 0.8

Insert operator (+,-,*,/) : E
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you! I don't really yet understand most of what you wrote. Since it's our first week learning C, our teacher didn't require nor teach us to check the return. I put the space in the line that I scan the operator and it fixed the problem! I just wanted to ask why. Why can I scan a double, for example, like scanf("%lf", &a); but can't scan a charachter like scanf("%c", &op);?

Comment: Because when using `scanf()`, all numerical *conversion specifiers*, such as `"%lf"`, `"%d"`, etc.. **ignore whitespace**. Spaces, tabs, carriage returns and newlines are *whitespace*. The character, "`%c"` and character-class `"%[...]"` *conversion specifiers* **do not** ignore whitespace and `"%c"` happily reads the newline (`'\n'`) left unread after the digits were read and converted with `"%lf"` -- which is one of the primary pitfalls that trap new C programmers. Adding whitespace in your *format-string* consumes all whitepace at that position in the input. Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not skipping operator, but just in the 2nd while loop iteration receives `\n`, entered after "second number", in 1nd loop iteration. You need skip out all `\n\r` chars before operator. You can do it, for example, by adding do/while around sscanf(op), like:

```
 10         printf("Insert operator: \n");
 11         do
 12             scanf("%c", &op);
 13         while(op <  040);
```

Or, more nice solution:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 
  3 int main()
  4 {
  5     double a, b; char op;
  6     for( ; ; )
  7     {
  8         printf("Insert operator[+-*/], a, b: ");
  9         fflush(stdout);
 10         char buf[100];
 11         fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
 12         sscanf(buf, "%c%lf%lf", &op, &a, &b);
 13 
 14         switch(op)
 15         {
 16             case '+': printf("%lf \n", (a + b)); break;
 17             case '-': printf("%lf \n", (a - b)); break;
 18             case '*': printf("%lf \n", (a * b)); break;
 19             case '/': printf("%lf \n", (a / b)); break;
 20             case 'E': return 0;
 21         }
 22     }
 23 }
```